# Are there any system calls besides fork that don't return once?

Tags: linux, operating-system, system-calls

I know fork returns twice, once for parent and once for child, but are there any other system calls out there that do not return exactly once?

Answer (score 3):

Any system service that clones the parent process could have the same effect. Any fork variant (e.g. vfork) or clone service would do the same.

Answer (score 2):

exit(); // does not return at all